# If a div contains a specific string of text, change background-color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: Look]

I'd love some help with a simple jQuery script that searches for a specific string of text. If that text exists, then manipulate the containing div's css.

The HTML+CSS+JS would look like:

```js
$(".ng-cell .ngCellText ng-scope col8 colt8 a:contains('Assigned')").each(function(i , v){
    $(this).closest(".ng-cell").css("background-color" , "green");
});
```

```css
.ng1582937649646 .colt8 {
    width: 140px;
}
.ng1582937649646 .col8 {
    width: 140px;
    left: 1175px;
    height: 40px;
}
.ngCellText, .ngCenteredCellText {
    padding: 0 5px 0 10px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: OpenSansLight,OpenSans,Helvetica;
    text-transform: none;
}
.ngCellText, .ngCenteredCellText, .ngHeaderText {
    padding-left: 10px;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.ngCellText {
    padding: 5px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-style="{ 'cursor': row.cursor }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell  col8 colt8" style="cursor: pointer;">
 <div class="ngVerticalBar ngVerticalBarVisible" ng-style="{height: rowHeight}" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }" style="height: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
 <div ng-cell=""><div class="ngCellText ng-scope col8 colt8" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text="" class="ng-binding">Assigned</span></div></div>
</div>

<div ng-style="{ 'cursor': row.cursor }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell  col8 colt8" style="cursor: pointer;">
 <div class="ngVerticalBar ngVerticalBarVisible" ng-style="{height: rowHeight}" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }" style="height: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
 <div ng-cell=""><div class="ngCellText ng-scope col8 colt8" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text="" class="ng-binding">In Progress</span></div></div>
</div>

<div ng-style="{ 'cursor': row.cursor }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell  col8 colt8" style="cursor: pointer;">
 <div class="ngVerticalBar ngVerticalBarVisible" ng-style="{height: rowHeight}" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }" style="height: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
 <div ng-cell=""><div class="ngCellText ng-scope col8 colt8" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text="" class="ng-binding">Assigned</span></div></div>
</div>
```

Why won't the Assigned div background-color change to green ? What am i missing ? Will help me a lot if someone can point me in right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue is with your selector. It's very specific and targeting elements that don't exist. The second issue is your call to `closest`, which is looking for a parent with a class of "ng-cell" instead of an attribute. This seems to work:

```js
$(".ngCellText span:contains('Assigned')").each(function(i , v){
    $(this).closest("[ng-cell]").css("background-color" , "green");
});
```

```css
.ng1582937649646 .colt8 {
    width: 140px;
}
.ng1582937649646 .col8 {
    width: 140px;
    left: 1175px;
    height: 40px;
}
.ngCellText, .ngCenteredCellText {
    padding: 0 5px 0 10px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: OpenSansLight,OpenSans,Helvetica;
    text-transform: none;
}
.ngCellText, .ngCenteredCellText, .ngHeaderText {
    padding-left: 10px;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.ngCellText {
    padding: 5px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-style="{ 'cursor': row.cursor }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell  col8 colt8" style="cursor: pointer;">
 <div class="ngVerticalBar ngVerticalBarVisible" ng-style="{height: rowHeight}" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }" style="height: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
 <div ng-cell=""><div class="ngCellText ng-scope col8 colt8" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text="" class="ng-binding">Assigned</span></div></div>
</div>

<div ng-style="{ 'cursor': row.cursor }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell  col8 colt8" style="cursor: pointer;">
 <div class="ngVerticalBar ngVerticalBarVisible" ng-style="{height: rowHeight}" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }" style="height: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
 <div ng-cell=""><div class="ngCellText ng-scope col8 colt8" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text="" class="ng-binding">In Progress</span></div></div>
</div>

<div ng-style="{ 'cursor': row.cursor }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell  col8 colt8" style="cursor: pointer;">
 <div class="ngVerticalBar ngVerticalBarVisible" ng-style="{height: rowHeight}" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }" style="height: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
 <div ng-cell=""><div class="ngCellText ng-scope col8 colt8" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text="" class="ng-binding">Assigned</span></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`ng-cell` is not the *class* of the element, you can try using *attribute selector*. Also there is no `a` element which you are looking through the selector, it is the `span` element you are looking for. Please note, if you want to refer an element with multiple classes please remove the spaces between them:

```js
$(".ngCellText.ng-scope.col8.colt8 span:contains('Assigned')").each(function(i , v){
  $(this).closest("[ng-cell]").css("background-color" , "green");
});

//OR: simply using the single class
/*
  $(".ngCellText span:contains('Assigned')").each(function(i , v){
    $(this).closest("[ng-cell]").css("background-color" , "green");
  });
*/
```

```css
.ng1582937649646 .colt8 {
    width: 140px;
}
.ng1582937649646 .col8 {
    width: 140px;
    left: 1175px;
    height: 40px;
}
.ngCellText, .ngCenteredCellText {
    padding: 0 5px 0 10px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: OpenSansLight,OpenSans,Helvetica;
    text-transform: none;
}
.ngCellText, .ngCenteredCellText, .ngHeaderText {
    padding-left: 10px;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.ngCellText {
    padding: 5px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-style="{ 'cursor': row.cursor }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell  col8 colt8" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <div class="ngVerticalBar ngVerticalBarVisible" ng-style="{height: rowHeight}" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }" style="height: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
  <div ng-cell=""><div class="ngCellText ng-scope col8 colt8" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text="" class="ng-binding">Assigned</span></div></div>
</div>

<div ng-style="{ 'cursor': row.cursor }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell  col8 colt8" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <div class="ngVerticalBar ngVerticalBarVisible" ng-style="{height: rowHeight}" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }" style="height: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
  <div ng-cell=""><div class="ngCellText ng-scope col8 colt8" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text="" class="ng-binding">In Progress</span></div></div>
</div>

<div ng-style="{ 'cursor': row.cursor }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell  col8 colt8" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <div class="ngVerticalBar ngVerticalBarVisible" ng-style="{height: rowHeight}" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }" style="height: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
  <div ng-cell=""><div class="ngCellText ng-scope col8 colt8" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text="" class="ng-binding">Assigned</span></div></div>
</div>
```